# "On Hold" for 2 Months on arXiv

Tags: publications, arxiv

I submitted a Physics Education pre-print to arXiv more than two months ago. It has been "on hold" ever since. The pre-print has nothing controversial. It is simply a few simulations of relativistic phenomenon which may be helpful for undergraduate students. It has been under review at an AAPT journal. I am applying for my PhD and every pre-print helps. I am thus wondering which of the following I should do:

1. **Delete this submission and re-submit the same pre-print.** I did this earlier this year with another physics pre-print which had been on hold for two weeks, and it was published the next day. It sounds surprising, and indeed I was taken aback when this worked earlier this year, but I am hesitant to do it this time. Why? Well, I've already waited two months. If I delete and re-submit the pre-print, what if I have to wait another two months?
2. **Ask arXiv what's going on.** I've already done this twice, and they repeatedly respond by stating that they cannot provide comments on individual submissions.
3. **Something else?** I could contact the editor for Physics Education on arXiv, but I have heard that is not recommended for some reason. Is this true? Is there anything else I can do? I should note that I have three other pre-prints already published on arXiv.

Update: I appealed for an arXiv moderation decision. Here's what I received in response:

> Dear arXiv user,

> We have received your inquiry regarding the “on hold” status for your submission. Unfortunately we do not have the resources to provide submitters with continual status updates for their submissions. All submissions to arXiv go through moderation screening and dozens of papers per day have some delay. Your work has not been singled out in this regard.

> Your submission is currently on hold pending a decision by our volunteer moderators. The "Hold" status indicates that our moderators need additional time to consider your article. We have reminded our moderators that a decision is needed regarding your submission.

Comment: I will not go with option 1 because it might delay the process. Option 2 is recommended. To request moderators Choose the first option [here](https://arxiv-org.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/2).

Comment: @learner Hi, I've done this. Please see the above.